# How to remove all HTML tag by using the loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id='images'><img id='center_loadingImage' align='middle' src='loading.gif' alt='Loading Image'></div>
```

How to remove all `<div>` with the loop with Javascript?

[image: images]

Here is my code:

```
var value = document.getElementsByTagName("images");
for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    $(value[i]).remove();
}
```

Comment: use `class` instead of `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use same id value once per page. Change it to class, i.e. `images`

You will then have multiple `div` with class `images` and will be able to easily remove the spinners like this:

```
$(".images").remove();
```

If you have a lot of spinners, just wrap them with a div and remove the div. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="jedi-wrapper">
    <div class="images">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#jedi-wrapper").remove();
```

From the image, it looks like you are loading some values using AJAX. Why don't you remove the image on success?

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your code. `$("#WebPartWPQ1 table table").after("<div id='images'><img id='center_loadingImage' align='middle' src='loading.gif' alt='Loading Image'></div>");` This creates many `<div>` tags whenever the data loads. How can I remove all the `<div>` with your idea?

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you want to remove all `div` with `id` images, but `id` is unique, you can use class instead:

```
<div class='images'><img class='center_loadingImage' align='middle' src='loading.gif' alt='Loading Image'></div>
```

then you can do:

```
$('.images').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code you can do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("images").remove();
```

or more like jQuery:

```
$('.images').remove();
```

---

Althoug you can try this too:

```
var value = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
   $(value).eq(i).remove();
} //-------^^^^^^--------------you can make use of `.eq()` here
```

---

What your issue is there is no tag name like `'images'` as your var suggests.

```
var value = document.getElementsByTagName("images");
```

`images` is the class name so you can use this:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("images")
```

Answer (score 1):

Get element by ID, there's nothing with document.getElementsByTagName("images")

```
var c = document.getElementById('images');
var i, item = c.childNodes;
for (i = item.length; i--;) {
    c.removeChild(item[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using `class="images"` instead of `id="images"` if that element is being rendered multiple times.

But to do this in a loop with raw javascript, you will need to first get the elements, convert them to an array, and then remove them in a loop.

```
var imageElements = doc.getElementsByClassName('images'),
    images = Array.prototype.slice.call(imageElements);

for (var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++) {
    images[i].remove();
}
```

Notice that I don't just loop through `imageElements`... That's because `getElementsBy...()` returns a **live list**, so as soon as you `remove()` one of them, the list will be mutated and you will start running into `undefined` elements and javascript errors. To solve this, simply convert the live list to an array with `Array.prototype.slice.call()` and then loop through that array, removing the elements from the page.